# Why does get_dirsize return the same size?

Tags: uploads

The function below is intended to return the size of the base directory. Although additional files have been uploaded, it continues to display the same size. What am I missing?

```
function get_space_used() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $space_used = number_format( get_dirsize( $upload_dir['basedir'] ) / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 1 );
    return $space_used;
}
```

Comment: @kero you should post that as an answer

Comment: Just did it @TomJNowell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood, `get_dirsize()` uses [`recurse_dirsize()` which uses a transient called `dirsize_cache`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/recurse_dirsize/#source). Try clearing that transient and check again.

To do so, you can use one of the following methods:

- call [`delete_transient('dirsize_cache');`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_transient/)
- use WP CLI's [`wp transient delete`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/transient/delete/)
- use [a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/transient/)

---

Looking further through the source code, I think it should be possible to use `recurse_dirsize()` directly in your code and telling it not to cache like so:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$size = recurse_dirsize($upload_dir['basedir'], null, null, []);
```

By passing an empty array `[]` as the fourth argument, it should circumvent the cache because the [`!isset($directory_cache)`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/5.9/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L8188) now returns a different result.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to disable the transient or alternatively is there another option that doesn't use a transient?

Comment: Did you check that the issue was resolved when deleting the cache? You could call the method directly and set `$directory_cache` to something so it doesn't use transients.

Comment: Yes, it does. Which method are you referring to? I've currently added `delete_transient('dirsize_cache');` to the start of the function `get_space_used()`. I'm unsure if it's optimal and/or if it's the recommended way of achieving the outcome. I don't quite follow setting `$directory_cache`.

Comment: @Motivated I've added an example. Clearing the transient every time is probably not a good idea - it is there to cache the result to take load off the server. If the transient was wrong just this one time, it could be OK to use `get_dirsize()` regularly after all (without clearing transient first).

Comment: How does bypassing the cache differ to deleting the cache from a load perspective? Would it not be the same?

Comment: @Motivated For your function it would be the same. For all other functions that use `get_dirsize()`, they would still get the cached value. The interesting question would be why the cached value is wrong .. but that is quite difficult to determine